# Issue in width style in html5

Tags: html, css

I have been created simple web page, using html5 and css, css3.

I have created sticky footer, Here is the code:

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   color:#000;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#fff;
}
```

and wrap and header styles:

```
#wrap
{
    width:100%;
}
header
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

from my above code, my page look like this: http://s2.postimg.org/6t4qokwxl/Untitled_1_copy.png

I need to show footer as full width, but when i remove `margin:0 auto;` from header, the footer shows exactly full-width and didn't show header properly.

I need to show except footer width as 960px; and footer need to as full-width.

I am struggling , can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your HTML as well. If possible, reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer without knowing how your HTML is structured, but judging from the screenshot, you need to add `left: 0`to the footer CSS, otherwise it will have its left position at the same left edge as its nearest containing block (which looks like it is the `#wrap` element).

Tip: next time, include a link to a running code example with your post. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do as per this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u9he2jjp/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  
  Content!
      
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```